# Is $e^{{e^{\ \dots\ }}^n}$ ever an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer. It is clear that $e^n$ is not integer because $e$ is transcendental (not algebraic).

Now for each positive integer $k$ let $F^k(n)$ denote the $k$-fold composition of $F(n)=e^n$.

Is $F^k(n)$ ever an integer?

I am also (primarily) interested in this question for compositions of the function $F(n)=e^n-1$.

It seems to me that the answer should be no in each case. I'd like to see a proof if it's fairly simple, or just a reference if this is known but complicated.

Comment: I am not sure what is a good way to write the title in MathJax. Wikipedia article about [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Notation) uses something like: `$e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{n}}}}$` which gives $e^{e^{\cdot^{\cdot^{n}}}}$.  I have asked [in the MathJax chatroom for advice](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13752/2022/9/28). Feel free to revert to the original title, if you prefer that one.

Comment: This function is widely denoted $\exp$. Writing $\exp^{\circ k}(n)$ makes the notation essentially self-defined.

Comment: [Somewhat related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/430797/84253) on MSE, also with an answer conditional on Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: Why do you think it could be an integer and not a rational number?

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao [$e^\pi$ is transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant). Maybe you're thinking about $\pi^e$, which is an entirely different kettle of fish.

Comment: @TimothyChow yes I realized $e^{\pi}$ is provably transcendental last night, but didn't delete this comment. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Didn't we have a question about $e^{e^{e^{74}}}$ here some years ago?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652454/why-it-were-conjectured-that-eee79-is-not-an-integer-only-for-n-7? and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245845/is-ee9-an-integer? and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/eee79-and-ultrafinitism and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13054/how-to-show-eee79-is-not-an-integer

Answer (score 21):

The impossibility of this would follow from [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) but I would be surprised if it was known unconditionally. Let $q$ be rational and let $e_k = \exp^k(q)$, so that $e_0 = q$. We will show the stronger result that all the $e_k, k \ge 1$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, by induction (so in particular they are all transcendental). The base case is the unconditional result that $e_1$ is transcendental. In general, if we know that $\{ e_1, \dots e_k \}$ are algebraically independent, then $\{ e_0, \dots e_k \}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, so by Schanuel's conjecture it follows that

$$\mathbb{Q}(e_0, \dots e_k, \exp(e_0), \dots \exp(e_k)) = \mathbb{Q}(e_0, \dots e_{k+1})$$

has transcendence degree at least $k+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $e_0 = q$ is rational it follows that $\{ e_1, \dots e_{k+1} \}$ are algebraically independent, as desired.

**Edit:** Also, since we can replace $\exp$ with $\exp - 1$ in the statement of Schanuel's conjecture and generate the same field either way, the same is true for the iterates of $\exp - 1$.

Comment: specifically I think it is open whether $e^{e^{e^e}}}$ is an integer.

Comment: $e^{e^{e^{e}}}$ has only 1656521 digits, and $e^{e^{e^{e}}} = x + 0.2212029...$ where $x$ is an integer. You might be thinking of the open problem about whether $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^{\pi}}} \in \mathbb{Z}$. (The number $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^{\pi}}}$ has about $6 \cdot 10^{17}$ digits.)

Comment: ... perhaps take $\pi/2$ instead of $\pi$ ... At least this is definitively no integer  ;-)

Comment: I'm amazed that e^e^e^e is so much smaller than pi^pi^pi^pi.

Comment: There is a [Stand-up Maths video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdHFLfv-ThQ) about $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$.